# Generating numpy array of indices for a deduplicated set of points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deduplication

I have an array of a minimum of 10s of thousands of points (up to 3 billion) some of which are duplicated.  I'd like to deduplicate the points and generate an index array which retains the original sequence of the duplicated points.

For example:

```
x = [(0, 0),  # (x1, y1)
     (1, 0),  # (x2, y2)
     (1, 1),  # (x3, y3)
     (0, 0)]  # (x4, y4)
```

Deduplicating x, we have y:

```
y = list(set(x)) = [(1, 0),  # (x2, y2)
                    (0, 0),  # (x1, y1) and (x4, y4)
                    (1, 1)]  # (x3, y3)
```

And then we would have a resulting index array, z:

```
z = [1,  # (x1, y1) 
     0,  # (x2, y2)
     2,  # (x3, y3)
     1]  # (x4, y4)
```

Is there a numpy-like way of obtaining z?  Here's a brute-force implementation:

```
z = []
for each_point in x:
    index = y.index(each_point)
    z.append(index)
```

Comment: Don't want to be pedantic but I don't see any `numpy` in here. More important: I don't think you can create a `numpy` array containing tuples as elements. Finally: `numpy.where` is the function you could be using on a numpy `array` but it's expensive if you need to locate (many) elements.

Comment: I think using numpy in the question would be obfuscating the actual question, which is really looking for parity with that brute force implementation.  I looked at where before posting, but I didn't see an example that matched up with what I wanted to do.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18197790/1461210) is almost exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Actually, I had the same (type of) problem some time ago and I also didn't find a good solution. The python list + set + dict 'brute force' approach was (a lot) faster than using numpy; indexing into a numpy array is horribly slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x2 = np.ascontiguousarray(x).view(np.dtype((np.void, x.dtype.itemsize * x.shape[1])))
y_temp, z = np.unique(x2, return_inverse=True)
y = y_temp.view(dtype='int64').reshape(len(y_temp), 2)
print(y)
print(z)
```

yields

```
[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]]
```

and

```
[0 1 2 0]
```

Credit: [Find unique rows in numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I think this provides 'z', but  I need both y and z.  If I understand what happened here, I would then need to construct 'y' from a sorted 'z'.   y = np.array(sorted(tuple(x[idx]) for idx in np.unique(z)))

Comment: Not at all, I just ignored the unpacked values (and only kept the indices). See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be elegantly solved using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author). It is similar to the solution posted by Alex under the hood; but with a nicer interface and more tests:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
y, z = npi.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
```