# Removing arrays which contain duplicate elements in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, duplicates

Suppose I have an array like so:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3]
 [2, 3, 3, 4]
 [4, 3, 2, 1]
 [1, 1, 2, 3]]
```

I need to remove all rows containing duplicate elements, to obtain:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3]
 [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

I'm thinking there's a way to do this with advanced indexing, but show me whichever way is most efficient.

Comment: You had the right intuition there that `advanced-indexing` might help. Posted a solution based off it in the linked dup question - [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136720/). Do check that out!